# How to disable click outside of the confirm function?

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio

I am trying to disable click outside the confirm message in JS. Is there any simple solution for this issue? If the confirm message show up on mobile, and i click outside of it.. it will dissapear, but i need it to stay as it is.

```
 if (confirm("Are u sure?")) {
    
 }
```

I am also using this function in webview. Maybe there is a problem? Anyone have any suggestions?

EDIT: I found the problem is in the webview.
I am using AlertDialog builder and i do not calling the function setCanceledOnTouchOutside();

Comment: It's a bad idea to use `confirm` or `alert` in the first place.

Comment: @connexo yes, they block the thread.

You can use a modal or something.

Comment: @Blaze_droid thank you for your feedback. I had no idea about it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For anybody in the future, who is making jsAlert with builder.
You just need to call .setCancelable(false) before .create(); in Android Studio project.

Answer (score 1):

You can use model to disable click outside. You want to set the backdrop value to static. You may also want to set the keyboard property to false because that prevents the modal from being closed

**In JS:**

```
$('#myModal').modal({
    backdrop: 'static',
    keyboard: false
})
```

or **in HTML**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
```